# XCTAssertNoThrow doesn't compile when called in closure

Tags: swift, xctest

Trying to compile a test case where the `XCTAssertNoThrow` is used within a closure with no luck. Why's that so rigid, does it rethrow or what's going on?

```
let e = expectation(description: "Wait")

distillery.produce(request: Request(bottles: 1337)) { (result) in // error
  XCTAssertNoThrow(try result.unwrap())

  e.fulfill()
}
```

Xcode throws an error during compilation:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()'
>   to non-throwing function type '(Result) -> Void'

ps: this seems like a bug in Swift I think https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-487

Comment: Alas, it's Xcode. In fact, it seems, the autoclosure causes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by wrapping `XCTAssertNoThrow` into a helper function

```
func assertOk<T>(_ result: Result<T>, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try result.unwrap(), file: file, line: line)
}
```

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 10.1. Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: What is the Result type?

Comment: @Ruben `enum Result<T, E> { case success(T), failure(E) }`. A call to `unwrap()` either returns `T` or throws `E`.

Comment: Xcode 10.2.1: I fear, we have to stick with this workaround for a while.